# Exiting a thread that Receives Data Forever

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to figure out how to properly exit this thread, as It's causing me a ridiculous amount of heart-ache, and calling Thread.Abort() isn't doing it.

```
    while(isRunning) {
        Debug.Log ("Running");
        while((messageFromServer = DataIN.ReadLine ()) != null) {
            Debug.Log ("Message from server: " + messageFromServer);
            HandlePacket(messageFromServer);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, the thread is constantly waiting on data to come in from the server, and it doesn't skip over it if there isn't any data there. This is what I was trying to accomplish with this while() loop.

I need it to be setup so that if there isn't any data to process, it finishes off the thread and executes again, instead of waiting for there to be data, processing it, THEN ending the thread.

How can I do this effectively?

EDIT: For those of you who may ask, DataIN is a StreamReader and messageFromServer is a string.

Comment: A timeout might be nice. Your problem isn't exiting the thread - it's the fact that the thread waits forever.

Comment: you could call .interrupt() on the thread to make it thrown an interrupted exception while on that blocking call.

Comment: Look at the ReadLineAsync method of the StreamReader.

Comment: Also, the tasks library was sort of written for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can exit the thread simply by returning from the delegate passed into the thread creation.

In this case, the thread will exit as soon as the server is done sending data.  You could add a timeout to the underlying stream to prevent "hangs" if the server isn't responding quickly enough, ie:

```
DataIN.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = 2000; // 2 second timeout
while((messageFromServer = DataIN.ReadLine()) != null) {
```

Note that this may raise an `IOExeception` when the timeout occurs, which you will likely want to handle.

Comment: Alright, this is my first networking application, would you recommend the server send packets constantly to the client just for this? Like a packet to see if the Client is still connected? If so how often should they be sent, and what would you recommend the data being? Just a single bit?

Comment: @ChristianTucker If there's a timeout, the connection will close.  The server can tell the client dropped off because they're connection dies.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that while trying it out, the problem is I need it to consistently check for new data. Is that where sending packets a few times a second would come in handy to just verify that they are still connected? (And to, of-course, allow the thread to close), because even if I set the boolean `isRunning = false` it will continue to wait on that data. Normally this isn't a problem, but the GameEngine I'm using doesn't like to handle Threads.

Comment: @ChristianTucker Can you use ReadLineAsync?  Would let you wait without blockign

Comment: I'm using Java for the Server-backend if that matters, however on the C# client I do not see an option available for `ReadLineAsync`.

Comment: I'm limited to using .NET 3.5 as I'm writing this for a Unity Game.